# How to access the chart title with OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an excel file with a Chart in it. I want to be able to modify the chart title with code.  Here is what I have so far:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, true))
{
   WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;
   var wsparts = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.ToArray();
   WorksheetPart wsp = GetWorksheetPartByName(myWorkbook, "Sheet1");
   if (wsp.DrawingsPart != null)
   {
         ChartPart chartPart = wsp.DrawingsPart.ChartParts.First();
         //how can I access the chart title here..?
   }
}
```

After I get the chartPart handle of the chart, how do I access the chart title?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create chart:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart>(
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart());
```

Then call method:

```
AddChartTitle(chart, "My Chart Title");
```

Write a method to access the title:

```
private static void AddChartTitle(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart, string title)
    {
       var ctitle = chart.AppendChild(new Title());
       var chartText = ctitle.AppendChild(new C.ChartText());
       var richText = chartText.AppendChild(new RichText());
        
       var bodyPr = richText.AppendChild(new BodyProperties());
       var lstStyle = richText.AppendChild(new ListStyle());
       var paragraph = richText.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        
       var apPr = paragraph.AppendChild(new ParagraphProperties());
       apPr.AppendChild(new DefaultRunProperties());
        
       var run = paragraph.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run());
       run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.RunProperties() { Language = "en-CA" });
       run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text() { Text = title });
       ctitle.AppendChild(new Overlay() { Val = new BooleanValue(false) });
        
      }
```

Comment: I fail to understand how this is the answer to the posed question. The question asks for accessing the title, where the answer explains how to add a new title.

Comment: @Rich_Rich, user mean to add/edit title. If you can add title, obviously you need to access the title